# Proof based problem in probability theory.

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a real random variable $X$ and a set $M$ included in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$P(X=x)>0,\forall x\in M.$$
Demonstrate that the set $M$ is finite or countable.

We start by considering for all $n\geq 1$ the set 
$$M_n=\{x\in M:P(X=x)\geq 1/n\}.$$
Then we have that 
$$\underbrace{\frac{|M_n|}{n}\leq P(M_n)}_{\text{why is the inequality true?}}\leq P(M)\leq 1.$$
I am also not sure why $|M_n|<\infty?$ Perhaps someone can explain.

PS: Sorry for the previous post!

Comment: It comes down to showing that $M$ is countable sum of finite sets. Which you can do by considering sets of points with $P(X=x)>1/n$

Comment: Zero-context question after 3+ years on the site and 300+ questions asked, why?

Comment: @Did Hi, Sorry for the abrupt question. I have fixed it! Hope it is better now.